# What is the late-binding for HTML parsing getElementsByTagName in VBA?

Tags: vba, html-parsing

Given the following HTML code:

`<td>blabla</td>`

I would like to use getElementsByTagName in VBA to get the result **blabla**.

I have been trying to search around a lot, but all posts I see involve using the Internet Explorer as an object. I would like to write a macro where the HTML code is already given beforehand, so no IE objects or scraping.

I'm really struggling which late-bind objects to define to get it to work.

```
Sub Parser()
    Dim HTMLcode As Object

    HTMLcode = "<td>blabla</td>"

    TestVar = HTMLcode.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(0).innerText
    Debug.Print TestVar
End Sub
```

The above code obviously does not work but I feel like I have reached a dead end. How should I define `HTMLcode` to get the above macro to output **blabla**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following...

```
Sub Parser()

    Dim htmlDoc As Object
    Set htmlDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile") 'create an new instance of an HTML document

    Dim htmlCode As String
    htmlCode = "<table><td>blabla</td></table>" 'must include table element
    
    htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = htmlCode

    Dim TestVar As String
    TestVar = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(0).innerText
    
    Debug.Print TestVar
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! But why is <table> necessary?

Comment: Without it, the `getElementsByTagName` method fails to find the `td` element.